# How to create an object from the matches of multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given `array1` and `array2` I should create an object where the properties and the values come from the intersection matches between the two arrays.

```
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, cb) {

    var obj = {};   
    var newArray1 = array1.map(cb);

    for (let i = 0; i < newArray1.length; i++) {
        if( !(array2.indexOf(newArray1[i]) == -1) ) {           
            obj[newArray1[i].toLowerCase()] = newArray1[i];
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], function(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }));
// should log: { hi: 'HI', bye: 'BYE', later: 'LATER' }
```

Is there a better or cleaner way to write this than this implementation?

Comment: why is the callback inside of the function?

Comment: I'm having an hard time figuring out what is the sense of the callback here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to build an object only adding the key where a match is found.

```js
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, cb) {
  return array1.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (array2.includes(cb(item))) obj[item] = cb(item)
    return obj
  }, {})

}


console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], function(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}));
```

This is simple, but it will have O(n²) behavior because `includes` looks through `array2` for every item in `array1`. This may not matter for small lists, but if the lists are large it may be worth making a hash of some sort (like a `Set` or object) to give you constant time lookups into `array2`.

Something like:

```js
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, cb) {
  let set = new Set(array2)
  return array1.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (set.has(cb(item))) obj[item] = cb(item)
    return obj
  }, {})

}


console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], function(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is quite unclear what the function is supposed to do, which makes it hard to read. Instead you should seperate the tasks:

```
  const intersection = (a, b) => a.filter(it => b.includes(it));
  const toMap = (values, mapper) => Object.assign({}, ...values.map(value => ({ [mapper(value)]: value })));

  const matches = intersection(array1.map(it => it.toUpperCase()), array2);
  const result = toMap(matches, value => value.toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and map the common parts for a new object.

This approach takes two loops, one for every array.

```js
function objOfMatches(array1, array2) {
    var s = new Set(array1);

    return Object.assign(...array2.map(v => s.has(v) && { [v.toLowerCase()]: v }));
}
console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'].map(s => s.toUpperCase()), ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the upcoming [`fromEntries`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-from-entries). **Huge caveat** - current browser compatibility is just Firefox atm [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

But: simply map over the two arrays to merge them, then `fromEntries` on that merged array to give you the object.

```js
function objOfMatches(arr1, arr2) {
  const merged = arr1.map((el, i) => [el, arr2[i]]);
  return Object.fromEntries(merged);
}

const result = objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello']);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```js
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, cb) {
    return array1.reduce((op,cur,i)=>{
      if(array2.includes(cur.toUpperCase())){
        op[cur] = array2[i];
      }
      return op;
    },{})
}
console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello']));
// should log: { hi: 'HI', bye: 'BYE', later: 'LATER' }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Based on custom forEach and Reduce from previously in the exercise** at http://csbin.io/callbacks

```
function forEach(array, callback) {
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        callback(array[i])
    }
}

function reduce(array, callback, initialValue) {
    for(let i of array){
        initialValue = callback(initialValue, i)
    }
    return initialValue
}

function objOfMatches(array1, array2, callback) {
    let index = 0
    return reduce(array1, (acc, el) => {
        if(callback(el) == array2[index]){
            acc[el] = array2[index]
        }
        index++
        return acc
    }, {})
}
```

If you're using the in-built reduce functionality you can pass the index to the  callback automatically:

```
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, callback) {
    return array1.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
        if(callback(el) == array2[index]){
            acc[el] = array2[index]
        }
        return acc
    }, {})
}
```